# Java: Can i print a JFrame/JPanel as it looks on screen?

Tags: java, swing, printing

If i design a `JFrame/JPanel` with labels, tables, textfields etc, is it possible to print it as it looks on screen?

If so, what size parameters should i keep in mind? Considering it's an A4 page, how should i go about sizing my JFrame/JPanel?

Thank you. : )

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the printing example at [Exampledepot: The Quintessential Printing Program Using a Printing Service](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.print/BasicPrint.html).

Use this in conjunction with `SwingUtilities.paintComponent` to draw the image you want to print.